# Polymer CLI and require

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-cli

I am trying to build a Polymer 3 component that has a dependency on a library that uses Node's require to function. Can I use the Polymer CLI serve and build components that have node style required file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Polymer uses the ES6 Module syntax and NodeJS uses CommonJS Module syntax `module.exports` not ES6 module syntax `export` keyword.

So it is not possible by default to use the nodejs `require` within polymer project.
**Rob Dodson** from the polymer team created an [**experimental project**](https://github.com/robdodson/spock-cli) to achieve what you are looking for, but it seems the project did not see the light